# Rally App2.0 - Retrieve a specific story

Tags: rally, agile-central

I am getting the hang of 2.0, but a bit stuck on something that seems simple.

Basically, I have created a new app for my team to use (thanks all for the help).  I thought it would be cool to have a way I could add messages to the dashboard.

I decided the easiest way to accomplish this, is to create a story and in my code simply query that one story, grab the description and show it in the app.  Sounds easy enough right?

I am having a bit of a time simple running out grabbing the Description field and showing it.  I know it sounds odd, but it seems so complicated.  I have tried this way

```
            showMessage: function (message) {
                debugger;
                this.add({
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html: message
                });
            },

            getMessage: function () {
                var defectStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                    model: 'UserStory',
                    fetch: ['Description'],
                    filters: [{
                        property: 'FormattedID',
                        operator: '=',
                        value: 'US13258'
                    }],
                    autoLoad: true,
                    listeners: {
                        load: function (store, records) {
                            debugger;
                            if (records)
                                return records[0].get("Description");
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
```

But seems to get caught up in event spaghetti.  Surely there is an easier way :)

Just want to go grab a specific stories description field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a model's load method to do this:

```
var storyOid = 12345;

//Get the story model
Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
    type: 'UserStory',
    success: function(model) {

        //Load the specific story
        model.load(storyOid, {
            fetch: ['Description']
            success: function(record) {

                //success!
                var description = record.get('Description');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This did the trick, I didnt quite understand the default models, but this sums it up pretty good.  Only issue I had was .getDescriptin was not valid.  I ended up with record.data.Description.  Thanks for the help !

Comment: Yep- my fault.  Should have been record.get('Description');

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're trying to do it with a listener, but I would just call load and get the result upon success, like so:

```
getMessage: function (storyID) {
    var defectStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
        model: 'UserStory',
        fetch: ['Description'],
        filters: [{
            property: 'FormattedID',
            operator: '=',
            value: storyID
        }],
        autoLoad: true
    });

    defectStore.load({scope: this, callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        if(success){
            console.log(records[0].get('Description')); // additional logic here
        } else {
            console.log('You ruined the store. Jerk.');
        }
    }});
}
```

I'm thinking you might have some issues, though, unless call showMessage after you check for success, as extJS operates asynchronously.